# Permission's для чтения файлов других приложений в /data/data/%appname%

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Ребята, может кто знает, какие в android нужны permissions для чтения файлов других приложений в /data/data/%appname% ?

WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE и READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE недостаточно, уже указаны. В настройках ("Приложения" -> "Разрешения приложений") тоже галочки на доступ к памяти поставлены.

И есть ли возможность такого доступа без root?

Например, new File("/data/data/com.android.chrome/") в моем приложении считается пустой папкой, хотя там отображается много файлов и папок в Root Explorer.

Comment: без рута не получится. только если у приложения есть свой контент провайдер, через который вы и сможете работать с внутренним хранилищем приложения

Comment: А если с root - то все равно, какие конкретно нужны permission's? Контент провайдер - это, насколько я понимаю, свой API у каждого приложения для работы с этой директорией?

Comment: на счет рута не знаю, что там с пермишнами, никогда его не ставил и вам не советую) второе - да. контент провайдер вам даст ровно тот доступ, Какой разрешили разработчики приложения. ну и апи обязано быть